# Toggle play pause ImageView inside listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapter

I have a list view of songs with play and pause button in every row.
Obviously, I can't have two pause Icon(two playing song)at the same time in my list view So I need to first reset all of them to play Icon then set the selected view to pause Icon.
How can I achieve this?

This is what I have done so far:

In the model class ( Product ):

```
 public boolean paused = true;

 private int PlayPauseId;
   public int getPlayPauseId(){
    return PlayPauseId;
 }
public void setPlayPauseId(int playPauseId) {
PlayPauseId = playPauseId;
}
```

in **Adapter**:

```
public interface PlayPauseClick {
void playPauseOnClick(int position);
}
private PlayPauseClick callback;
public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
    this.callback = listener;
}
.
.
.


    holder.playPauseHive.setImageResource(product.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPauseHive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.playPauseOnClick(position);
            }
        }
    });
```

my Callback inside my **Activity**:

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    final Product product = movieList.get(position);
    if (product.paused) {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        product.paused=false;
    }else {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        product.paused = true;
    }
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check condition in your `getView()` method of adapter like this:

```
    if (product.paused) {
            holder.playPauseHive.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }else {
            holder.playPauseHive.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this will not solve my current problem